# Django database populate not working correctly

Tags: python, django

I'm building a script to populate a db with info from a json but when It finishes the only saved objects is the last. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
def setup_environment():
    pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(pathname))
    sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(pathname), '../')))
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings'

setup_environment()

import django
django.setup()
from stats.models import Champion, Item  #import models for django 

import json

with open("champions.json", "r") as fjson:

    data = json.load(fjson)
    print len(data)

    for i in data:
        #print data[i]["name"], data[i]["key"]
        champ = Champion.objects.get(key = data[i]["key"])
        champ.global_kda = data[i]["global_kda"]
        champ.kills = data[i]["kills"]
        champ.assists = data[i]["assists"]
        champ.deaths = data[i]["deaths"]
        champ.save()
```

Link to all the code: 
https://gist.github.com/zanklord/bc667dab9864af951446

Comment: Shouldn't you use read() ?  [json.load doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: Could you please post also the json file? At least an excerpt, just to show us the data structure.

Comment: @tgdn why? Actually it is not the problem and is not a bad practise or anything else, I think

Comment: @YábirGarcia no no you are right but we don't know where the error comes from I was just saying. But it works, so my bad

Comment: How many `Champion` objects are in your DB?

Comment: @help_asap a simple part of code is too long for the editor so I posted it on github https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb6be04729f49309e2b0

Comment: @Filly there are 124 objects

Comment: is that your *exact* code ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers acctually it is longer but I cant post it all. Here you have a link to all https://gist.github.com/zanklord/bc667dab9864af951446

Comment: How can you be sure that the only object modified and actually saved into the DB is the last one of the json file? How do you check it? Beside, have you tried debugging the script by putting some `print` into the `for` loop ? At every iteraction the right and _different_ data are processed?

Comment: There is some wrong indentation in your gist, or it is how your code is actually written?

Comment: @help_asap I cheked with prints the for loop before posting and only the last item is printed.

Comment: The code in your gist is badly indented, and the way it's indented would lead to the problem you describe. Fix you indentation.

Comment: @help_asap sorry, it changed the indentation I dont know why. In my code it is right indentent, if not I would get an indentation error

Comment: @help_asap Here is good. I don't knwo why pasting on github changes the indentation

Comment: @help_asap I did nothing but I fixed it. Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: I did nothing too... but you are welcome =) Anyway, it's a common problem: indentation errors are very sneaky, sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what I really did because I did nothing. I modified the file in gist and copied the same in my computer. Before it was right indentent as @help_asap suggested. Anyway thanks to @help_asap